# How to filter for frequency across two categorical variables in data set?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am interested in figuring out the frequency of unemployed people, who are also African-American/Black in my data set. I have a large data set, that includes the variables OCC (unemployed individuals are coded as 0), and Race (AA/Black is coded as 2).

I tried to use the group(by) function thru tidyverse, but I think I may be doing this incorrectly, because I get the following error messages.

This is the code:

```
RACE <- group_by(cps_data, OCC, RACE)
occupation <- summarise(RACE,
                   count = n(),
                   OCC = mean(OCC, na.rm = TRUE)
)


summarise(RACE, occupation = mean(OCC, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The occupation object that I created gives me the error message:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `OCC` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable
```

The summarise function gives me a tibble that doesn't seem very helpful:

```
# A tibble: 1,374 x 3
# Groups:   OCC [?]
     OCC  RACE occupation
   <int> <int>      <dbl>
 1     0     1          0
 2     0     2          0
 3     0     3          0
 4     0     4          0
 5     0     5          0
 6     0     6          0
 7     0     7          0
 8     0     8          0
 9     0     9          0
10    10     1         10
```

Here is some of my data - I tried to reproduce for you guys to help you assist me. You will see that above I made another data frame to only include OCC and RACE, as those are the only relevant factors at the moment.

```
dput(head(cps_data,4))
structure(list(YEAR = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), DATANUM = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), SERIAL = c(1029644L, 1029644L, 1029705L, 1029708L
), CBSERIAL = c(403, 403, 1944, 1964), HHWT = c(194L, 194L, 142L, 
77L), STATEICP = c(14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), STATEFIP = c(42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L), CITY = c(5330L, 5330L, 5330L, 5330L), GQ = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), PERNUM = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), PERWT = c(194L, 140L, 142L, 
78L), SEX = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), AGE = c(37L, 35L, 60L, 41L), RACE = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), RACED = c(100L, 100L, 200L, 200L), OCC = c(800L, 
6260L, 0L, 350L), IND = c(7270L, 770L, 0L, 8190L), INCWAGE = c(75000L, 
25000L, 0L, 83000L)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am looking to get an output that shows me the number of individuals unemployed, who also identify as African-American/Black, so I can compare across my data set.

Comment: You may need to `ungroup` and group by `RACE` alone i.e. `RACE %>% group_by(RACE) %>% summarise(n = n(), OCC = mean(OCC, na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you were almost there.

```
df %>%
    group_by(OCC, RACE) %>%
    summarize(count = n())

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   OCC [4]
    OCC  RACE count
  <int> <int> <int>
1     0     2     1
2   350     2     1
3   800     1     1
4  6260     1     1
```

#### Data

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(YEAR = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), DATANUM = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), SERIAL = c(1029644L, 1029644L, 1029705L, 1029708L
    ), CBSERIAL = c(403, 403, 1944, 1964), HHWT = c(194L, 194L, 142L, 
    77L), STATEICP = c(14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), STATEFIP = c(42L, 42L, 
    42L, 42L), CITY = c(5330L, 5330L, 5330L, 5330L), GQ = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), PERNUM = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), PERWT = c(194L, 140L, 142L, 
    78L), SEX = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), AGE = c(37L, 35L, 60L, 41L), RACE = c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L), RACED = c(100L, 100L, 200L, 200L), OCC = c(800L, 
    6260L, 0L, 350L), IND = c(7270L, 770L, 0L, 8190L), INCWAGE = c(75000L, 
    25000L, 0L, 83000L)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```